# PHPUnit composer installation on WAMP not working

Tags: phpunit, composer-php

I am following a Lynda.com Tutorial and can't get PHPUnit to work.

Here is what I did:

Project folder: C:\wamp\www\stats

In this folder I have a composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "stats": ""
        }
    }
}
```

I ran the composer command:

```
>composer update
```

It created a new folder C:\wamp\www\stats\vendor containing many subfolders, even /Symfony...??

Then I opened cmd.exe and wanted to run phpunit:

```
>cd C:\wamp\www\stats\
>phpunit
```

But it doesn't work. Error message:
Command "phpunit" not found

Can anyone help?

Comment: try to find phpunit in vendor folder and run something like `vendor\bin\phpunit`

Comment: it shows a list with all options etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.composer):

For a system-wide installation via Composer, you can run:

```
composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=5.0.*"
```

I recommend to not use version as of last stable is 5.2

Note that you should use version ^4.8 for php < 5.6

Also you need to add [composer folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27692321/1809433) (`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`) to your [path enviroment variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)