# Can't Setup Laravel Project Using Composer

Tags: php, laravel

I try to setup a laravel project using composer with this command

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "5.1.*"
```

But i got following error:

```
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error




[RuntimeException]                                                           
  Error Output: PHP Warning:  require(/home/iwan/blog/bootstrap/../vendor/aut  
  oload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/iwan/  
  blog/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17                                       
  PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/iwan/blog/boots  
  trap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pea  
  r') in /home/iwan/blog/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

Does anybody know how to fix this ?

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to give  permission to the project folder.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468625/laravel-5-failed-opening-required-bootstrap-vendor-autoload-php

Comment: I try to change to 777 mode to blog dir still got same error.

Comment: You need to run composer install after create product

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the project is created but the dependencies are not installed so open your terminal/command prompt and run following commands:

```
cd blog
composer install
```

Also, if you want then, you may install the `Laravel installer` so you can create a new project using something like the following:

```
laravel new Blog
```

This is a little bit faster. So to install the `installer` you need to run the following command from the command prompt/terminal:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Once you install the `installer` you may then run `laravel new someproject` from the terminel to create a new project with all the dependencies ([According to Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0#install-laravel)).

---

*Note: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373188/laravel-installation-how-to-place-the-composer-vendor-bin-directory-in-your) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059397/is-there-any-way-to-install-composer-globally-on-windows) as well if needed.*