# how to update composer in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want instaler the LexikFormFilterBundle but when I made the command composer update in the console I got this error even though the call is set :
Cannot run program "composer" (in directory "C:\wamp\www\esen-ecommerce"): CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier spécifié est introuvable

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
C:\bin>echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat

set path=%path%;c:\bin
```

assuming that c:\binis the path where composer.phar is located

Sources:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

[Is there any way to install Composer globally on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059397/is-there-any-way-to-install-composer-globally-on-windows)

Comment: do you use composer.phar or composer.bat?

Comment: The specified path was not found.

Comment: which path c:\bin\composer? I just put it as an example. Where did you install your composer.bat file?

Comment: i use composer.phar but I got an error: the file not existe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059397/is-there-any-way-to-install-composer-globally-on-windows or https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

Comment: i installed in symfony