# No PHP binaries detected for symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, wamp

I have a project in Symfony 5 to code and since yesterday I try to create a project that shows me :

- (running C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar create-project symfony/skeleton C:\Users\Santhya\Desktop\agenda)

no PHP binaries detected

And also when i wrote symfony check:requirements on the command, show me that :

**no PHP binaries detected**

I've already installed wamp server, phpstorm, symfony and composer 
I followed a tutorial for the installation but despite that this error is displayed
How to add the PHP Binaries ?

Comment: Saw this as top result in google but I can't "answer" the correct answer. Run "symfony local:php:list -vvv" , then it will work. Source : https://github.com/symfony/cli/issues/195#issuecomment-680153230

Answer (score 1):

`Composer.phar` - is a PHP archive and it should be run via `php.exe`
Not sure if php.exe available from cmd without the full path, but if does, try to run like this:

```
php.exe C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar create-project symfony/skeleton C:\Users\Santhya\Desktop\agenda
```

---

Another way is to make composer global.
Here you can find how to do that:
[Is there any way to install Composer globally on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059397/is-there-any-way-to-install-composer-globally-on-windows)